# Immediately hide the navigation when browser width is reduced instead of showing a glimpse

Tags: jquery, html, css, navigation, responsive

I want to immediately hide the navigation when browser size is reduced to responsive. I'm using media query to control the nav layout. The code I've written is working but when I reduce the browser width, it will still show me a glimpse of the navigation and then slides to the left instead of just hiding itself immediately waiting for the menu button to be clicked.

Please see codepen: http://codepen.io/rezasan/pen/wWNxjR

HTML

```
<header>
  <div id="menu-toggle">MENU</div>
  <div class="header-bottom">
    <nav class="clearfix" id="topMenu">
      <div class="nav-group">
        <ul class="main-nav">
          <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="expertise.html">Expertise</a></li>
          <li><a href="projects.html">Projects</a></li>
          <li><a href="process.html">Process</a></li>
          <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>
```

CSS

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 65em){

#menu-toggle{
        width: 35px;
        height: 50px;
        position: absolute;
        top:0;
        cursor: pointer;
        left:0;
        color:red;
    }

.header-bottom{
        transform:translateX(-100%);
        -webkit-transform:translateX(-100%);
        -moz-transform:translateX(-100%);
        -o-transform:translateX(-100%);
        -ms-transform:translateX(-100%);
        top:0;
        height: 100%;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: #000;
        z-index: 1;
        transition:transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(.91,.12,.46,.8);
        -webkit-transition:-webkit-transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(.91,.12,.46,.8);
        -moz-transition:-moz-transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(.91,.12,.46,.8);
        -ms-transition:-ms-transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(.91,.12,.46,.8);
        -o-transition:-o-transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(.91,.12,.46,.8);
    }

   .slide{
        transform:translateX(-0%);
        -webkit-transform:translateX(-0%);
        -moz-transform:translateX(-0%);
        -o-transform:translateX(-0%);
    }

}
```

JS

```
$('#menu-toggle').click(function(){
        $('.header-bottom').toggleClass('slide');
});
```

Comment: You want to slide header with animation?

Comment: Yes I've did that part. Now when I resize the browser the header will slide to the "ready" position. I want it to be hidden immediately. Then when I click "Menu", then the navigation slide and display the menu.

Comment: Hey there, Now you can see the answer.!! :)

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is change the following css:

```
.header-bottom{
    transform:translateX(-101%);
        -webkit-transform:translateX(-101%);
        -moz-transform:translateX(-101%);
        -o-transform:translateX(-101%);
        -ms-transform:translateX(-101%);
}
```

You can try it on CodePen.

Comment: Hi Yashwardhan, could you try to resize the browser to the breakpoint? Did you see the layout change and then being translated? I actually wanted the navigation to hide immediately and not show the animation. It looks like an error when I resize the browser. It shows the new layout for the breakpoint and then it slides to the left.

Comment: So you don't want sliding animation right? Just wanna hide it anyway.

Comment: Yeah, I've tried all that you have said, and the same code worked really fine, without an error!!

Answer (score 0):

So I figured it out. I need to display:none to hide the nav first

```
.header-bottom{
    transform:translateX(-100%);
    -webkit-transform:translateX(-100%);
    -moz-transform:translateX(-100%);
    -o-transform:translateX(-100%);
    -ms-transform:translateX(-100%);
    top:0;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #000;
    z-index: 1;
    transition:transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(.91,.12,.46,.8);
    -webkit-transition:-webkit-transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(.91,.12,.46,.8);
    -moz-transition:-moz-transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(.91,.12,.46,.8);
    -ms-transition:-ms-transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(.91,.12,.46,.8);
    -o-transition:-o-transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(.91,.12,.46,.8);
    display:none;
}
```

On JS, need to fadeToggle and toggleClass.

```
$('#menu-toggle').click(function(){
    $('.header-bottom').fadeToggle().toggleClass('slide');
});
```